# What's the relationship between bitwise capacity and bit capacity?

Tags: c#

In **Conversions** (on Chapter 2) in C# topic in **C# 5.0 in a Nutshell**, the author says:

> ...Conversions can be either *implicit* or *explicit*: implicit conversions happen automatically, and explicit conversions require a *cast*. In the following example, we *implicitly* convert an **int** to **long** type (which has twice the bitwise capacity of an **int**)...

This is the example:

```
int x = 12345;      // int is a 32-bit integer
long y = x;         // Implicit conversion to 64-bit integer
short z = (short)x; // Explicit conversion to 16-bit integer
```

Is there a relationship between bitwise capacity and bit capacity? or, what is author´s point respect to bitwise capacity?

Answer (score 2):

I think, he wants to differntiate between "bitwise capacity" and "numeric capacity".

In the example, the data types differ in bitwise capacity: int has 32, long 64 and short 16. In this case, conversions to data types with higher capacity happen implicit, conversions to data types with lower bitwise capacity happen explicit.

On the other hand, there's something like "numeric capacity" where int and uint do share the same number of bits (they have the same "bitwise capacity"), but are still not fully compatible in terms of values you can store (uint has no support for negative values).

Answer (score 1):

It is the same thing. It just means that you have twice as many bits to represent your value, which means you can store much larger numbers. Numeric capacity is therefore tied to bitwise capacity since the more bits the higher numeric capacity.

With a 64 bit data type you can represent your value using 64 bit binary numbers

Answer (score 1):

I think they mean “capacity, with respect to bits”. If they had left out the “bitwise” part, then it could easily be interpreted as “this type holds twice as many values as the other type”, which is wrong: it holds much more than twice the number of values. It holds twice the number of bits, which increases the number of values exponentially.